# Change with CSS the default "checkbox"

Tags: css, checkbox, default

I would like to change the default checkbox on my site to look like the Mozilla Firefox checkbox "http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/checkbox/ff2-xp.png" .

Can please somebody help in order how to do this please?

I was thinking in doing this with the help of css....

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
background: url(checkbox_image_url_here);
width: 12px; height: 12px;
```

... Can I achieve something with this?

Hope somebody can help me. thank you everybody

Cheers
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a CSS only way of doing this, you'll be limiting yourself.

I suggest checking this [link](http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/2009/07/17/using-css-to-style-radiobuttons-and-checkboxes-for-safari-and-chrome/) out for how to do it and [here](http://acidjs.wemakesites.net/using-css-to-style-radiobuttons-and-checkboxes-for-safari-and-chrome.html) is a working version of it, for a CSS only solution. This only works on Safari and Chrome, unfortunately to get this working on other browsers, you'll need [javascript](http://acidjs.wemakesites.net/forms-js.html) of some sort.